# Sending email within .NET Task not working in console application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application, task

I have the following code below.  This runs at the end of my console application.  I am not receiving emails that go out when it is done within the task, but when I comment out the task factory method it works?  The code gets his both times with a breakpoint but the async email flow doesn't ever send out the email.  Any reason why?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{ 
    var smtp = new SmtpClient();
    try
    {
        var toEmails = mailMessage.To.ToList();
        var bccEmails = mailMessage.Bcc.ToList();

        foreach (var email in toEmails)
        {
           mailMessage.To.Clear();
           mailMessage.To.Add(email);
           mailMessage.Bcc.Clear();

           smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       Logger.Error(ex);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the return type of Task which gave me the option to wait or not.

```
 var task = _emailService.Send(new List<string> { @event.ContactEmail }, subject, body,
                    new List<Attachment>
                        {
                            new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), report.FileName, "application/pdf")
                        });

                if (task != null)
                {
                    task.Wait();
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

As you say *"This runs at the end of my console application"*, i am assuming your `Main` method is terminating before `Task.Factory.Startnew` has a chance to finish running your code in the background thread.

You should either:

1. Run this code synchronously, without starting a new thread (this would be my recommended approach)
2. Explicitly wait for the task to finish using `Task.Wait` while blocking the execution of your `Main` method, which misses the point of using a `ThreadPool` thread at all (i wouldn't do this):

   ```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   { 
      var smtp = new SmtpClient();
      try
      {
         var toEmails = mailMessage.To.ToList();
         var bccEmails = mailMessage.Bcc.ToList();

         foreach (var email in toEmails)
         {
            mailMessage.To.Clear();
            mailMessage.To.Add(email);
            mailMessage.Bcc.Clear();

            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.Error(ex);
      }
   }).Wait();
   ```

**Edit**

I had to add that i would advice you **NOT** to consume the code from the common library, for a few reasons:

1. It previously returned void and was spinning a redundant `ThreadPool` thread to do IO based work
2. This will cause you to have to use `Wait` on a new thread, you dont need that.

If you want to consume a true async api (one which doesn't need to use a thread to execute IO bound work) you can use [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) and simply `await` on it:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
try
{
    var toEmails = mailMessage.To.ToList();
    var bccEmails = mailMessage.Bcc.ToList();

    var taskMails = toEmails.Select(email => 
    {
        var message = new MailMessage
        {
            To = email
        };

        smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(taskEmails);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Logger.Error(ex);
 }
```

Comment: I know anyway around this???? I tried the Task.Wait and it worked but it misses the point like you said.

Comment: Why do you need to execute this in a background thread at all? why not run it synchronously before your console terminates?

Comment: Well it's a common class used elsewhere in a web application that processes emails in a thread for a faster response time.  I am just reusing it.

Comment: A console application inside a web application? im confused.

Comment: I think im missing the bigger picture of this method. What are you attempting to do here?

Comment: That code I am using is inside a common class used in other applications.  I went ahead and made the return type of Task instead of void for the option to wait.

Comment: Well, if this was used in a common class it doesn't mean that it will work for you in a console application, those are two different environments. What advantages are you expecting to gain from running this in a background thread on a console app?

Comment: As you posted the calling method, i see what you're talking about. It looks you could either `Wait` on the returned `Task`, or simply extract the code from the common library and run it synchronously (which would be the better choice in your case). Plus, i wouldn't want to use an api which spins up a threadpool thread behind the scenes without me knowing about it, that is bad practice

Comment: I am almost sure (if we assume that your config is ok) that operation failed because main console thread is terminated as Yuval already suggested. If you want to reuse your library just extend your function declaration with parameter which will allow you to send an email sync or async.

Comment: I will look into that email async, never seen that before.